# Is there Linq to Nhibernate for stateless session?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I was using regular session for loading some items from database via linq. The problem is that it caches the entities and memory load increases very much unnecessarily. Is there a way to replace session with stateless session without introducing many changes in client code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118108/how-do-i-totally-disable-caching-in-nhibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use Linq with IStatelessSession.

You can use all the other query methods (Get, Criteria, HQL and SQL).

Update (2010-07-19): I believe Steve might be adding this to the NH 3.x provider)

Answer (score 6):

Linq support for stateless session is included in version 3.1.0 See the release notes:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2211

Answer (score 0):

Have you got lazy loading turned on?

I don't have any experience with LINQ to NHibernate, but in my application, lazy loading makes a huge difference in performance.

Comment: The problem is hight memory consumption. During memory profiling I found out that memory is not released by garbage collector. The problem turned to be first level caching which cannot be disabled. Memory is cleaned though after session is closed.